# Listar os 10 Produtos mais vendidos

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, criteria, hsqldb

Preciso listar os 10 produtos mais vendidos de uma tabela usando Hibernate.

A tabela **item_venda** tem as seguintes colunas:

- quantidade
- id_produto
- valor_unitario
- valor_sub_Total

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Os itens mais vendidos seriam aqueles mais presentes na tabela item_venda. Nesse caso, você precisaria apenas criar a consulta SQL ordenando os itens pelo sum de quantidade por produto, i.e., pelo número de ocorrências de um produto considerando sua quantidade na tabela item_venda. O sql ficaria:

```
select sum(quantidade), id_produto from item_venda group by id_produto
order by sum(quantidade) desc;
```

Pronto, agora você tem os ids dos produtos mais vendidos em ordem decrescente (o mais vendido primeiro, os menos vendidos depois). Agora, se você precisar de outras informações do produto mais vendido é só criar uma subquery para trazê-las com base nos ids que você recuperou:

```
select * from produto p join
(select sum(quantidade), id_produto from item_venda group by id_produto
order by sum(quantidade) desc) itensMaisVendidos on (p.id = itensMaisVendidos.id_produto)
```

Pronto, o que foi feito na consulta acima foi trazer primeiro todos os produtos e depois contabilizar a venda de cada um deles através do sum e group by. Utilizando o join é feita a comparação do id do produto com o id do produto mais vendido, assim não irão aparecer resultados repetidos devido ao produto cartesiano feito através do join entre as tabelas.

Comment: Mas espera, veja que se eu for listar apenas pela quantidade de ocorrência  do **id_produto** a consulta seria equivocada, por exemplo: o produto x, ocorre 5 vezes na tabela item_venda, mas o produto y ocorre apenas 1 vez e tem a **quantidade** == 6, veja que o produto mais vendido foi **produto y** e não o x, como eu poderia fazer essa consulta levando em consideração também a quantidade vendida.

Comment: +1 você é fera! =D

Comment: Ahhh, se tem quantidade lá você troca o count(*) pela sum(quantidade). Simples assim :)

Comment: Muito Obrigado :D

Comment: Funcionou corretamente, porém preciso fazer isso utilizando Hibernate, já tentei utilizando Projections porém sem sucesso, poderia me ajudar? Desde já agradeço...

Comment: Rapaz, acho melhor usar createSQLQuery (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm) porque subquery com HQL é complicado, nem sei como seria feito nesse caso.